# Dynamic DNS for the domain root

Tags: dynamic-dns

I have a host set up with Dyn, and the IP address for this host is dynamically updated by my router.

My domain's DNS is delegated to Dyn, and I've set up subdomain CNAME records which alias the host, e.g. www.example.com now forwards to example.dyndns.org

Is it possible to get example.com to point to the Dyn host as well? It won't let me create a CNAME record for the root domain.

I don't want to use the webhop option.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/170194/why-cant-a-domains-root-be-a-cname

Comment: Thanks Zoredache. Is it just not possible to use the root address when you use dynamic DNS then? I was hoping there might be another solution that I've missed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good news - Dyn got back to me today and the answer is simple: rather than having the router update the IP for a "host" (e.g. example.dyndns.org) that the CNAME records point to, the router can just update the main A record (example.com) for the domain directly.

My setup now is as follows:

- A record for example.com updated by the router
- CNAME records for
  www.example.com and other subdomains all point to the A record

I'm not sure which accounts let you do this - mine is called [Dyn Standard](http://dyn.com/dns/dyn-standard-dns/), and costs $29 per year.